# Replacing "==" with bitwise operators

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

Using only bitwise operators (|, &, ~, ^, >>, <<) and other basic operators like +, -, and !, is it possible to replace the "==" below?

```
int equal(int x, int y) {
    return x == y;
}
```

Comment: This is mostly to understand what is actually going on with "==" to see how the computer looks at the "==" on a bitwise level and to find if similar operators can be replicated in the same fashion.

Comment: @Jens: ["The homework tag...is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @not_l33t, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Comment: What are the requirements as you approach an int's limits? I.e. INT_MAX, INT_MIN? Or does it only have to work for a much smaller range?

Comment: I am fairly new to programming, and the question is more to understand how it works. With that in mind, it would be ideal to have an infinite limit, though I am beginning to see that that might not really be possible for me to figure out (bitwise manipulation works because of the 32 bit string).

Comment: I'd like to mention for anyone trying to use bitwise operations as a performance boost that at least in chrome 61 there is little to no difference between regular equals and bitwise equals methods. https://jsperf.com/bitwise-equal/1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Two numbers are equal if there is no difference between them:

```
int equal(int x, int y){
   return !(x-y);
}
```

Comment: Though not really using a bitwise operator.

Comment: @Yada: But it uses a "BASIC" operator :)

Comment: I have used this approach in combination with another approach (negating a variable). that way i could use a + instead, making it closer to what the computer reads. thus making it faster?

Comment: int equal(int x, int y){
   return !((!x+1)+y);
}

Comment: this may invoke undefined behavior if the result of `x-y` cannot be represented in `int`

Answer (score 82):

Remember that an `XOR` is the exactly same as `NOT EQUALS` and `XNOR` is exactly the same as `EQUALS`. So, the following will give you exactly what you want:

```
return !(x ^ y);
```

Comment: You're combining bit-wise with logical operators here, which may be confusing.

Comment: It's better than the accepted solution, because by definition XOR is faster than ADD (add have to transport carry, so it's not very scalable).

Comment: what if x and y both are zeroes

Comment: @Kapil: Huh? 0 XOR 0 equals 0, just as if x and y were any other same number.

Answer (score 20):

The C `!` operator is really just shorthand for `!= 0`, so using it seems very close to cheating :)

Here's my take just using bitwise operations, assuming a 32-bit two's complement machine with arithmetic right shifts (technically, in C arithmetic right shifts are undefined, but every C compiler I've ever seen on a two's complement machine supports this correctly):

```
int t = (x - y) | (y - x); // <0 iff x != y, 0 otherwise
t >>= 31; // -1 iff x != y, 0 otherwise
return 1 + t; // 0 iff x != y, 1 otherwise
```

That said, actual compilers don't have this problem. Real hardware actually has direct support for comparisons. The details depend on the architecture, but there's two basic models:

1. Condition codes returned for arithmetic operations (e.g. x86 and ARM do this). In this case, there's usually a "compare" instruction which subtracts two values, doesn't write back to an integer register but sets the condition code/flags based on the result.
2. More RISC-like platforms typically have direct "branch if equal" and "branch if less than" operands that do a comparison and branch based on the result. It's basically equivalent to the C code

   ```
   if (a == b) goto label;
   ```

   or

   ```
   if (a < b) goto label;
   ```

   all in one machine instruction.

Comment: excellent example! but why just not use "return t < 0 ? false : true" (if assume the method is boolean)?

Comment: As I understand it, the OP excludes branching

Answer (score 3):

This example is the same as subtraction, but is more explicit as to how some architectures do register comparison (like the ARM, I believe).

```
return !(1 + ~x + y);
```

The 1 signifies the carry-bit input into the ALU.  One number `x` is bitwise complemented.  Taking the complement and adding 1 produces the two's complement of the number (`x` becomes `-x`), and then it's added to the other number to get the difference to determine equality.

So if both numbers are equal, you get `-x + x => 0`.

(On a register level the `!` operator isn't done, and you just test the "zero bit" of the condition codes or flags register, which gets set if the register operation produces a result of zero, and is clear otherwise.)

Answer (score 2):

As XOR is same as (!=), hence (x ^ y) will return 0 only for equal values.
My take is the following because it is sensible, uses bit-wise operator and working.

```
int notEqual(int x, int y){
        return (x ^ y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Take on this

```
int equal(int x, int y){
   if((x & ~y) == 0)
       return 1;
   else
       return 0; 
}
```

Explanation: If `x == y`, then `x & ~y` evaluates to `0`  return 1, else return 0 as `x!=y`.

```
Edit1: The above is equivalent to 

int equal(int x, int y){
    return !(x & ~y) ; // returns 1 if equal , 0 otherwise. 
}
```

The above code fails in certain cases where the Most significant bit turns to 1. The solution is to add a 1. i.e correct answer is

```
return !(x & (~y +1) );
```

Comment: Two problems. 1) This checks if `y` has all the same bits as `x` set, *not* that `x == y`. 2) You're using `==` even though it is neither wanted nor needed.

Comment: 3) just return it instead of using an `if`.

Comment: I know is old, but what happens if `x` is negative? Lets say `x = -1` and `y  = 0` then how should `if ( !( x & ( ~( y + 1 )) ) )` Work ? How about if `x = -1` and `y = -1`? ´return x ^ y:` should work.