# Replacing “!=” with bitwise operators

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

using only bitwise operators `(|, &, ~, ^, >>, <<)`, is it possible to replace the `!=` below?

```
// ...
if(a != b){
    // Some code
}
/// ...
```

this is mainly out of self interest, since I saw how to do it with `==` but not `!=`.

Comment: a and b are uints? or strings?

Comment: how does bitwise operation make sense with strings?

Comment: not bitwise, but still worth mentioning? `if(a<b || a>b)`

Comment: @ajax333221 Incidentally, your solution is not entirely correct for floating point numbers; NaN is neither less than nor greater than any other value.

Comment: @willglynn and I suspect it is [neither equal](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.4) (note: at least that is the case in JavaScript)

Comment: @ajax333221 Quite so. Lesson: be careful with inequalities and floating point numbers! Just because you verified that a value is not less than X and not greater than Y does *not* mean it is between X and Y.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if(a ^ b) {
    //some code
}
```

should work.

You can also use your preferred method for `==` and add `^ 0xFFFFFFFF` behind it (with the right amount of Fs to match the length of the datatype). This negates the value (same as `!` in front of it).

Comment: Alternatively one can express `(a XOR b)` as `(((NOT a) AND b) OR (a AND NOT(b)))`, if XOR is unavailable.

Answer (score 3):

`a != b` means that there is at least one different bit in the bit representations of `a` and `b`. The XOR bit operator returns 1 if both input bit operands are different, 0 otherwise.

So, you can apply a XOR operation to `a` and `b` and check if the result is not equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using this:

```
if (a ^ b) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bitwise version of the '!=' test could look something like:

```
if((a - b) | (b - a)) {
    /* code... */
}
```

which ORs the two subtractions. If the two numbers are the same, the result will be 0. However, if they differ (aka, the '!=' operator) then the result will be 1.

**Note:** The above snippet will only work with integers (and those integers should probably be unsigned).

If you want to simulate the '==' operator, however, check out Fabian Giesen's answer in [Replacing "==" with bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161656/replacing-with-bitwise-operators)

Answer (score 0):

`x ^ y` isn't always sufficient.  Use `!!(x ^ y)`.  Values expecting a one bit return value will not work with `x ^ y` since it leaves a remainder that could be greater than just 1.

Answer (score -2):

"~" is equaled to NOT so that should work. example would be "a & ~b".

Comment: 15 & ~0 = 15. You need to think more in binary